# How can I add bundle to configuration?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, osgi-bundle, eclipse-rap

I want to use Pax logging in my application. So I need to add two bundles **org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-service** and **org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api**. How can I add those two bundles to run configuration of my application.

I mean can see them and choose in run configuration:[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see the bundles in the `Run Configuration` dialog you'll need to add them to the Eclipse `Target Platform`.

```
Window->Preferences->Plug-in Development->Target Platform
```

In there you can modify or create a new target platform that Eclipse builds against. If you make sure you add the directory with the PAX logging jar files you should then be able to select them in the `Run Configuration`.

To add the jars to an existing target platform select it in the `Target Definitions` list and click edit. The `Add` button at the right of the next dialog will allow you to add a `Directory`. Point this at the folder containing your jar files. Eclipse will scan the directory and add the jars to the target platform.

Comment: Could you tell me how to add jar file to the target platform?